# What is the structure and meaning of this sentence?

Tags: meaning, syntax

[Discussing the word *dis-eate* in *Macbeth*, amended by various editors to *disseat*, *disease*, *disseizes* and *defeat*. ]

> . . . you may say that Shakespeare actually intended, by putting down something a little removed from any of the approximate homonyms, to set the reader groping about their network. One must consider, before dismissing this second idea as absurd, that the Elizabethans minded very little about spelling and punctuation; that this must have given them an attitude to the written page entirely different from ours (the reader must continually have been left to grope for the right word); that from the comparative slowness, of reading as of speaking, that this entailed, he was prepared to assimilate words with a completeness which is now lost; that **only our snobbish ability of spelling imposes on us the notion that one mechanical word, to be snapped up by the eye, must have been intended**; . . .

From [*Seven Types of Ambiguity*](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=fJXv6cwu3EkC&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=%E2%80%9COnly+our+snobbish+oddity+of+spelling+imposes+on+us+the+notion+that+.%E2%80%9D&source=bl&ots=d3lA9AT5j9&sig=p8RREktABw4jkC8fqCJC4b7oh6M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Ob4-U4X4JofQlAXegoC4Cg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9COnly%20our%20snobbish%20oddity%20of%20spelling%20imposes%20on%20us%20the%20notion%20that%20.%E2%80%9D&f=false) by William Empson.

I'm trying to figure out the structure and meaning of the bolded part of this sentence.

Comment: I've added more context. If you will follow your last sentence with some account of just what gave you trouble with this, I think we can get this reopened.

Answer (score 1):

The basic structure is

> Only X imposes on us the notion Y.

That is, X is the only thing which causes us to believe Y.

X here is *our snobbish oddity of spelling*—by which Empson means the modern belief that our modern consistency in spelling is the only ‘right’ way to spell, and that Elizabethan practice is ignorant and inferior.

Y is the fallacy of assuming *that one mechanical word, to be snapped up by the eye, must have been intended*. Modern consistency in spelling means that any string of letters is immediately recognized as representing exactly one word. Empson suggests that this keeps us from seeing that Elizabethan irregular spelling gave writers an opportunity to set down ‘words’ whose exact meaning was ambiguous.

Comment: @user4550 *to be* here is an infinitive. It means approximately *which is expected to be snapped up*. That is, the modern author expects the reader to understand the word immediately, as if grabbing it quickly.

Comment: @user4550 Yes. It might be generally paraphrased "which is in a situation to be*, and the particular modal signficance - can, intend, may, &c - is inferred from context. *He is to go to London* means "He is expected to go to London". *We have a job to do* means *We have a job we must do*.

Comment: @user4550 Yes; but equally it can mean *should* but in context may mean *may* or *can*. There's not a 'default' meaning: context **always** governs.

Comment: @user4550 This is a very complex issue. It is certainly *possible*, but in complex texts it requires familiarity with the written dialect, which is syntactically far more complex than conversational dialects. The 'slow reading' movement came about because it has become obvious that schoolchildren are not being adequately exposed to complex texts and therefore have not mastered the written dialect.